# Should I use properties in interface in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm learning Kotlin and coming from Java world I find idea of properties in interfaces quite peculiar.

- What's the general consensus on properties in interfaces?
- Is it considered a good practice to have them?

I've seen few discussions on the related topic but for C# but none on Kotlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties in Kotlin are a shorthand to Java Beans naming convention, a read-only property is the same as a getter, a writeable property is a pair of getter and setter. You may use properties for Java getters and settings on Kotlin too. Same applies both to classes and interfaces.

Properties have shorted syntax and improve readability

Delegated properties in Kotlin helps to build come up with short and powerful code, e.g. `val lazyCompoutedVariable by lazy { computeIt() }`

Properties are likely to be cheap to call, the same code style is used, for example in C#

You may find more information on that in the documentation 
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html

Comment: Hey thanks, I get the idea behind properties in Kotlin. The question however is related to properties defined in interface. You can't define Java Beans in interfaces in Java. 
So the question is more related to -> is this feature of Kotlin considered a good coding practice?

Comment: Property in the interface is equivalent to getter (and probably setter) methods. It makes sense to have them there to make your code shorted and easier to read

Comment: Something that wasn't mentioned is that properties on interfaces can't have backing data, so it's always derived from something already on the interface. So, a property could be a computation that's a bit more convenient to something already on the interface. For example, say you have a Number interface, we could add a property isPrime perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

They are used in the standard library, e.g. [`CharSequence#length`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-char-sequence/length.html), [`Collection#size`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-collection/size.html) are just the first ones I've thought of. If the alternative is forcing them to be `getLength()`/`getSize()`, this seems obviously bad.

Do you remove `String#length`? Do you implement `length` for every implementation of `CharSequence` separately? Do you make `length` an extension property

```
val CharSequence.length get() = this.getLength()
```

? Only the last one seems remotely acceptable.

Or you can just have `val length` in `CharSequence` and no problems :)